# devo -- what does that word mean?

Tags: meaning

Please, take a look at this website: https://bibletalk.tv (a Christian website dedicated to Bible study)

There are four main sections on that website: *Home*, *Sermons*, *Series* which are multi-lesson Bible courses for personal, group or church bible studies and the last one called ***Devos***. What do you think this word means?

Comment: In another context, it is an 80's band. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what the website says:

> Short entries on current events and every day topics from a Christian perspective. Useful as devotional messages or discussion starters for small groups.

I think you may read "Devos" as short for "devotional materials" or "devotional messages".